# Back button unloads application after changes currentState of Android Application AIR

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

I am creating an application. At one view I have three states. If I changes state and than back button pressed it unloads the application.

I am developing it in Adobe AIR.

any one have any idea how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: My crystal ball is at the repair shop, so I'm not able to solve this problem without you giving more information. Code sample, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States are not views, they do not get stacked in the navigator. Back button will never go backward for your states. The back button will drop the view you push until it reach the view 0, then it'll exit the application. You can monitor what's going on with the back button by listening like this:

```
systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleCustomDeviceKeyUpHandler,false,10000);

private function handleCustomDeviceKeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace("handleCustomDeviceKeyUpHandler()")
    var key:uint = event.keyCode;
    if (key == Keyboard.BACK) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Comment if you don't want to prevent.
    }
}
```